# How can I use pivot table grouping by dates incremented by a day at a time?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have some data which has been extracted from staff timesheets which provides number of hours worked by a member of staff on a given day. I need to summarise this information grouping by days but only incrementing the start day by 1 each time not the number of days I am grouping by.

For example if I group by number of days=2 I get results of the form (using UK date format btw)

```
Date                    Hours
29/07/2014 - 30/07/2014 xx
31/07/2014 - 01/08/2014 xx
04/08/2014 - 05/08/2014 xx
06/08/2014 - 07/08/2014 xx
08/08/2014 - 09/08/2014 xx
```

What I actually want is

```
Date                    Hours
29/07/2014 - 30/07/2014 xx
30/07/2014 - 31/07/2014 xx
31/07/2014 - 01/08/2014 xx
01/08/2014 - 02/08/2014 xx
02/08/2014 - 03/08/2014 xx
```

In other words the start date only increments by one day at a time rather than by the number of days being grouped by.

I can't seem to find the pivot table magic needed to implement this so is something like this possible?

Comment: You want your data to overlap except the first day and the last day using your example of 2 day?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm not sure I understand exactly what you are saying - when you have a date in column a and a number representing hours in column b - sum(a2+b2) actually just increments the date in column a by the number of days in column b. Do you mean sum(b2+b3) to sum the hours. I tried something like this but I don't see how it will work with pivot tables.

Comment: I don't think this will work with pivot tables as they are basically designed to classify a row and put it somewhere once, not multiple times like this would have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a formula that adds the next row. This assumes the names and dates are in order. I also put logic in there so the adding of the next row only occurs if the name also matches. You will see in the example that when the name changes from John to Sarah, the value in HoursPlusNext is from the Hours cell.

[image: DATA]

From the data above, I was able to create a PivotTable. I have a feeling your data is a little ore complex, but I hope you get the idea about creating the calculation you need before creating the PivotTable.

[image: PivotTable]

Like gtwebb states, I don't think there's a way to overlap the data in the way that you want out of the box.

Finally, I will including [Excel 2003 XLS of the data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc8kjgmbnqpp9y4/hours_plus_next.xls?dl=0). Hopefully, this helps.